# How do I uninstall Python 2.5?

Tags: python, macos

I recently upgraded to Mac OS 10.6 and didn't realise that it shipped with [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) 2.6.
I installed Python 2.5.4 and now it is the default Python installation. 
Can I uninstall Python 2.5.4 and keep 2.6?

Answer (score 6):

While there is no uninstaller for the python.org OS X python installers (because they use the standard Apple installer mechanism which does not provide an uninstaller by default), it is not difficult to remove.  I've documented the full process [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue7107) but keep in mind that it doesn't hurt to have multiple python instances installed on OS X.

The key to managing it all is understanding where each instance is installed and how to manage your shell `$PATH` search order.  By default, the python.org installers modify your `.bash_profile` (or `.profile`) shell initialization file to add the python framework `bin` directory at the front of your `$PATH`, that is, before `/usr/bin` where the Apple-supplied `python` command is found.  You'll probably find the unmodified version saved as `.bash_profile.pysave`.  Do a `diff` first to make sure there aren't any other changes and then just `mv` it back:

```
$ cd ~
$ diff .bash_profile{,.pysave}
12,16d11
< 
< # Setting PATH for MacPython 2.5
< # The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
< PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin:${PATH}"
< export PATH
$ mv .bash_profile.pysave .bash_profile
```

Start up a new terminal session and verify that `python` is again `python2.6`.  (This assumes your default login shell is `bash`.)

If you want, you can then follow the instructions in the link above to actually remove all traces of the extra python.  Note, do not attempt to remove the Apple-installed default python files in `/usr/bin` and `/System/Library/Frameworks`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the uninstall utility of the same package manager you used to install it.

As a sidenote, you can just modify the PATH not to point to the 2.5.4 installation by default, and both can live happily side-by-side.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: which one? first tell use how you *installed* Python.

Comment: python 2.6 was already installed. i installed python 2.5.4 through the dmg i downloaded form python.org. now i have 2 installations. help me get one off...the path change method also sounds feasible.

Comment: interestingly, the path still points to python 2.6. but still when i type python at terminal, it launches python 2.5.4??

Comment: Ned: looks like your answer is much more helpful here. amit, I hope it helps you achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

Not only path but also link to `python` as it is now resolved as python2.5, not python2.6.